# I am trying to access custom cellRendererParams inside the CustomCellRenderer Class

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use Ag-Grid for my angular application and create a custom cell renderer. In the implementation that I have followed, it uses ICellRendererParams for the type of params being passed to the init event.

```
agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.type = this.params.type || null;
  }
```

But now when I try to access custom prop from that params the lint gives the error ***Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ICellRendererParams'.***. Which works perfectly fine when I change the type to ***any***. I have tried creating a custom model class inheriting from ***ICellRendererParams*** and adding a property type in it and using that class instead of ICellRendererParams. I wanted to ask if this is the right approach or is there any other cleaner approach to access a property from the interface.

Comment: Probably better for you to use the Context in the params. See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but this is the proper way to do it.

```ts
type ICellRendererParamsWithGridType = ICellRendererParams & { type: string;};

@Component({
  selector: 'cc-course-timing-grid-cell',
  templateUrl: './course-timing-grid-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-timing-grid-cell.component.scss'],
})
export class CourseTimingGridCellComponent {
  gridType!: string;
  getEntitiesToolTip
  constructor() {}
//...
}
```

Here we are using [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). The above code is the short-hand for,

```
interface CustomParamsType{
  type: string;
}
type ICellRendererParamsWithGridType = ICellRendererParams & CustomParamsType;
```